# Sign in with apple throws Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

So I am getting the following code and I am unsure why that would be?

Wondering if anyone knows what would cause this?

```
Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.radiomedia.drn.drn1}
something went wrong Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1000 "(null)"
```

Comment: I deleted my entitlements file -- instead just choosing to have the Apple Sign-In capability enabled from the 'Signing & Capabilities' section.

Comment: I had the same problem. My mistake was not adding the "Sign In with Apple" Capability to all the target outputs. i.e. I added the capability to "Profile" but not the "Debug" output.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Probably you forget to add "SignIn with Apple" capability in your plist file.
For this go to project file -> Capabilities Tab -> Turn on "SignIn With Apple".

Comment: Nope - mine is there in plist. Still have the error.

Comment: i am also getting error even after  adding  "SignIn With Apple".

Comment: I had the same issue, but turned out I only enabled it for release target and not all (I was using debug build)

Comment: Me too, had the same issue. I was testing on `debug` mode but when I switched to `release` it worked. You can change it at: Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Comment: Also still getting error

Comment: Getting error for me as well. Any workarounds

Comment: I just deleted the app and cleaned the project, it worked

Comment: Im getting 7003, does anyone know where to find references for these random code numbers??

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that the Sign in with Apple capability was set only for profile mode not debug mode while I was testing.

Make sure you have it set for all modes if that's what you need (debug, release and profile).