# Apple signin issue in Cocoa - MacOS, Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I implemented Apple sign-in, Google sign-in functionality for our Mac OS application. It really works well on Debug mode(Xcode build). I already added the **Sign in with Apple** in project settings -> Capability.

But it does not work when I export the package. I need to distribute the new package to our Team members and QA guys.

```
The Operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Auth orizationError error 1000.)
```

```
Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026
```

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Are there any other errors in `Console.app`?

Comment: It's the install version from the exported package. So I can't get more logs.

Comment: Alexander Here is the console log.
Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026

Comment: I already checked the following issues[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389908/sign-in-with-apple-throws-authorization-failed-error-domain-akauthenticationerr), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321233/com-apple-authenticationservices-authorization-error-code-1000), but I already did it

Comment: Your question needs to be improved. Please add the code you are using to sign in or even better provide a minimal app that reproduces the problem. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you. This error can be caused by many issues, such as the use of a non-release build, improper setup of the signin, among other things.