# Apple Sign In with .Net Maui app error - Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026"

Tags: ios, maui

I'm trying to get apple sign in working in my .net maui app but I'm getting the following error on ios (works fine on android/web)

```
Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=app.name}
```

This answer suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390291/1662619 that a missing plist entry is the issue but i have the following in my plist files (ios and mac)

```
<key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
```

I've tried adding the 'signing identity' by going to project > ios > bundle signing and selecting my 'distribution profile' and 'automatic' as my 'provisioning profile' (also tried the app-specific provisioning profile) but no luck.

Doesn't work on simulator or physical devices, debug or release (a comment on the linked answer suggests it might only be enabled for 'release' target)

Comment: Firstly, make sure you create an `Explicit App ID` on the Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles website and then go to the Identifiers section. Check if your created Bundle Identifier is there, click the Bundle Identifier and scroll down. Check if the `Sign In with Apple` is selected, click Edit and make sure the Enable as a primary App ID is selected.

Comment: This was part of it, thanks Alexandar

Answer (score 1):

I was just updating the `Info.plist` file and hadn't added the `Entitlements.plist` file, after adding that and referencing it in the csproj like so:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
        ...
```

I also then needed to re-do the certification/provisioning steps described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0 as i was adding a new entitlement.